# Jetty Connection

Tags: console, jetty

is there a way to log something into the server console with Jetty, specifically, when a person connects is there a way to print that into the console?

Anyone have any clue how to do any of this or can link me to websites explaining it?

I haven't found much on google about it at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of jetty? You can simply enable debug logging on the connectors or the like. Whatever it is that you exactly want/need to get logged.

However if you're simply looking for a request log have a look at this:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html#configuring-jetty-request-logs